# image won't load on the web it only prints the alt function

Tags: html

I am trying to upload this Image from my computer to a web page. But, it won't upload.

used different paths, however when I use (bit.ly/fcc-relaxing-cat(link)) in my src, it does load up the picture.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!--
    <head id="main">

    </head>
-->

    <div id="main">
            <title>Dr. Norman Borlaug</title>

    </div>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">Dr. Norman Borlaug</h1>
        <div id="img-div">
            <img 
            src="C:\Users\corne\Desktop\FreeCodeCampProjects\Project1\images\norman.jpg" alt="A man holding a crop">


        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

it show a picture of a man holding a crop.

Answer (score 0):

**Clients  usually can't request local file system.**
If you want to use absolute path you should do something like this:

```
<img src="http:\\localhost\img\picture.png"/>
```

Remember to add your image to the root folder.